# Woo-commerce storefront how to NOT hide search-bar on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I want to make my storefront theme not hide the build in site search `.woocommerce-product-search` on mobile devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following css

Method 1: https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-easily-add-custom-css-to-your-wordpress-site/

```css
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .site-search {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```